# Slide one DIV over another DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to slide down a div on top of all element on the page.
I have set z-index of sliding DIV to 999 but still not working.
Here is my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dharmesh_guna/MQr5g/2/) code. (select latest jQuery version on load)

You can see that on hovering over a last div of first row a DIV is being slide down beneath the other 2 DIVs on 2nd row.

Comment: I am getting this error in the console --- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hover' of null

probably at...
$("div.content table td").hover(function() {                       chk...may be this will fix

Comment: @SandeepRajoria : I have removed hover effect but still not fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update line 16 of your javascript code from:

```
$(this).next("div:(:visible)").css("position": "absolute");
```

to

```
$(this).next("div:(:visible)").css({"position": "absolute", "z-index": 1});
```

that shoud do the trick.
To see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/MQr5g/4/

Comment: Thanks lorenzo.....Your solution works fine in jsFiddle but still I am having the same problem to my original code

Comment: most probably there is some other code that conflict. try to cut off code since you replicate exactly what's on the jsfiddle example, if it works there, it *must* work on your own version